# MOXyJsonProvider bug when unmarshalling json array

Tags: json, jax-rs, moxy

I have a simple jersey resource, UserContentManager, that processes a simple ContentInput class.  Both classes are below.  The postHello method works fine when called using `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":1,"type":"a"}' localhost:50000/news/rest/hello` but the putHello method is failing when called with `curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '[{"id":1}]' localhost:50000/news/rest/hello`

It is failing in MOXyJsonProvider:598 (the line in bold below) because when it is unmarshalled, it is unmarshalled to `ArrayList<Property>` instead of `ArrayList<JAXBElement<Property>>` as the code is expecting i.e. Object value = jaxbElement.getValue() is an `ArrayList<Property>` not `ArrayList<JAXBElement>` like the cast.

Is this a bug in Moxy or am I doing something wrong?  The getArray method is working fine when returning an array.  I have tried it with and without @XmlRootElement on the ContentInput class but the results are the same.

```java
        JAXBElement<?> jaxbElement = unmarshaller.unmarshal(jsonSource, domainClass);
        if(type.isAssignableFrom(JAXBElement.class)) {
            return jaxbElement;
        } else {
            Object value = jaxbElement.getValue();
            if(value instanceof ArrayList) {
                if(type.isArray()) {
                    ArrayList<JAXBElement> arrayList = (ArrayList<JAXBElement>) value;
                    int arrayListSize = arrayList.size();
                    Object array;
                    if(genericType instanceof GenericArrayType) {
                        array = Array.newInstance(JAXBElement.class, arrayListSize);
                        for(int x=0; x<arrayListSize; x++) {
                            Array.set(array, x, arrayList.get(x));
                        }
                    } else {
                        array = Array.newInstance(domainClass, arrayListSize);
                        for(int x=0; x<arrayListSize; x++) {
```

*** Array.set(array, x, arrayList.get(x).getValue());***

```
                        }
                    }
                    return array;
```

---

```java
@WebService
@Path("/hello")
public class UserContentManager {

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response postHello(ContentInput input) {
    input.setId(input.getId());
    input.setType("clip" + input.getType());
    ResponseBuilder builder = Response.ok();
        builder.entity(input);
    return builder.build();
}

@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ContentInput[] putHello(ContentInput [] input) {
    return input;
}

@Path("/array")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ContentInput[] getArray() {
    return new ContentInput[] {
            new ContentInput(),
            new ContentInput()
    };
}
```

}

---

```java
public class ContentInput {
private int id;
private String type;

public ContentInput() {}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getType() {
    return type;
}
public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

You are hitting the following bug which we have fixed in EclipseLink 2.5.1:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/413760